# How can I programmatically open and save a PowerPoint presentation as HTML/JPEG in C# or Perl?

Tags: c#, perl, powerpoint, ole

I am looking for a code snippet that does just this, preferably in C# or even Perl.

I hope this not a big task ;)

Comment: I think your best bet would be some C# and the PowerPoint Interop assembly...  maybe try researching that.

Comment: Will the computer running the program have PowerPoint installed?

Answer (score 27):

The following will open `C:\presentation1.ppt` and save the slides as `C:\Presentation1\slide1.jpg` etc.

If you need to get the interop assembly, it is available under 'Tools' in the Office install program, or you can download it from [here (office 2003)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=3C9A983A-AC14-4125-8BA0-D36D67E0F4AD&displaylang=en).  You should be able to find the links for other versions from there if you have a newer version of office.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using PowerPoint = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

namespace PPInterop
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var app = new PowerPoint.Application();

        var pres = app.Presentations;

        var file = pres.Open(@"C:\Presentation1.ppt", MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoTrue, MsoTriState.msoFalse);

        file.SaveCopyAs(@"C:\presentation1.jpg", Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsJPG, MsoTriState.msoTrue);
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit:**
[Sinan's version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038019/how-can-i-programmatically-open-and-save-a-powerpoint-presentation-as-html-jpeg-i/1038290#1038290) using export looks to be a bit better option since you can specify an output resolution.  For C#, change the last line above to:

```
file.Export(@"C:\presentation1.jpg", "JPG", 1024, 768);
```

Comment: +1 for the C# solution (when I can vote again which should be in another eight hours or so ;-)

Comment: This is excellent. To all users of office 2010 and later, the library 'Microsoft.Office.Core' [lib is actually a COM library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5932794/microsoft-office-core-reference-missing), not an extension that needs to be loaded.

Answer (score 7):

As [Kev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038019/how-can-i-programmatically-open-and-save-a-powerpoint-presentation-as-html-jpeg-i/1038217#1038217) points out, don't use this on a web server. However, the following Perl script is perfectly fine for offline file conversion etc:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft PowerPoint';
$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;

use File::Basename;
use File::Spec::Functions qw( catfile );

my $EXPORT_DIR = catfile $ENV{TEMP}, 'ppt';

my ($ppt) = @ARGV;
defined $ppt or do {
    my $progname = fileparse $0;
    warn "Usage: $progname output_filename\n";
    exit 1;
};

my $app = get_powerpoint();
$app->{Visible} = 1;

my $presentation = $app->Presentations->Open($ppt);
die "Could not open '$ppt'\n" unless $presentation;

$presentation->Export(
    catfile( $EXPORT_DIR, basename $ppt ),
    'JPG',
    1024,
    768,
);

sub get_powerpoint {
    my $app;
    eval { $app = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('PowerPoint.Application') };
    die "$@\n" if $@;

    unless(defined $app) {
        $app = Win32::OLE->new('PowerPoint.Application',
            sub { $_[0]->Quit }
        ) or die sprintf(
            "Cannot start PowerPoint: '%s'\n", Win32::OLE->LastError
        );
    }
    return $app;
}
```