# Microsoft.Office.Core Reference Missing

Tags: c#, outlook, automation, com, ms-office

Using the example provided in [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/outlookconnector.aspx) I am struggling to work out where I can find the reference to the library Microsoft.Office.Core.

I am getting the error "The referenced component 'Microsoft.Office.Core' could not be found."

I only have office 2007 enterprise edition and outlook 2003 installed on this system. Could this be the cause of this? Otherwise which specific dll am I supposed to be referencing?

Comment: Tried both suggestions and still seem to be stuck. The question is what is the "COM Library appropriate for your system" in my case?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You can add reference of `Microsoft.Office.Core` from *COM components* tab in the add reference window by adding reference of `Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library`. The screen shot will shows what component you need.

[image]

Comment: .NET->Office (if PIA installed). See Spike's answer below.

Comment: I used "Microsoft Office **14.0** Object Library" (12.0 didn't exist) and it worked as well. Also, I had to delete the reference to "Microsoft.Office.Core" first.

Comment: Jazakallah Adil bhai. Worked for me.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2017 but I cannot see the the "Microsoft Office XX.X Object Library" in the COM tab. Do I need to install "Microsoft Office"?

Comment: @Kin Did you find out what to do? I'm also using VS 2017 and I don't see a reference to the office's libraries. Did you have to install Microsoft Office?

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Kin Once you add the reference from the COM tab, reference it in the class file with `using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

Comment: I used "Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library" (12.0 didn't exist) and it worked as well. Also, I deleted the reference to "Microsoft.Office.Core" first. This is when I have Office App (Office 365) installed version 18.2008.12711.0 and also Visual Studio 2019 installed along with Visual Studio 2005

Answer (score 35):

None of the above answer helped me, i was using Visual Studio 2017. What I did is, installed Office/SharePoint Development using Visual Studio Installer.

[image]

After that, I was able to see 'office', this assembly contains Microsoft.Office.Core.

[image]

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I looked under the *Assembly - Framework* list and could not find *office*.  I actually had to do do a *search* for office, just as you have indicated, in order to find the *office* assembly.  Once I added it, everything compiled.  Merci!

Comment: Note: to get to this view, I clicked on "tools" and "Get tools and Features".

Answer (score 18):

You need to download and install the PIA (primary interop assemblies) for the version of Office you are using. Once installed you can then add a reference to your project and they will be available from the add reference dialog. Here are the links to download them...

[Office 2010 PIA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=938fe8ad-583b-4bd7-a345-23250dc15855)

[Office 2007 PIA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=59daebaa-bed4-4282-a28c-b864d8bfa513&displaylang=en)

[Office 2003 PIA](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=3c9a983a-ac14-4125-8ba0-d36d67e0f4ad&displaylang=en)

Comment: Tried all three. No luck thus far!

Comment: Installed PIA but couldn't find them in "Add reference", but then it worked for me by adding the DLL from path directly e.g. C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\xxxx\....

Comment: I have been able to find the other PIAs but not Microsoft.Office.Core

Comment: Still doesn't show up in the COM list to add as reference

Answer (score 5):

After installing the Office PIA (primary interop assemblies), add a reference to your project -> its on the .NET tab - component name "Office"

Comment: Upvoted because this actually did it to me. Initially setting the references to .COM did not solve the problem.

Comment: Be nice to know where this .NET tab is

Answer (score 5):

If someone not have reference in .NET . COM (tab) or not have office installed on machine where visual was installed can do :

1. Download and install: *Microsoft Office Developer Tools*
2. Add references from:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Now there is a nuget package for that.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetOffice.Core.Net40/

First I didn't find office in COM, so tried this nuget and it worked!

Comment: Adding to answer: If you install an Office Interop lib through the NuGet package manager console (say PowerPoint or Excel), it looks to install this, too... the same does not seem to be true if you use the Visual Studio NuGet GUI

Comment: This is not by Microsoft, but by individual developer

Comment: Correction - NuGet PMC does not install this package as claimed in above comment.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this NuGet package which includes the interop assemblies in addition to the office assembly.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bundle.Microsoft.Office.Interop/

Comment: The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the package is deprecated, has security vulnerabilities or shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually gone to your references and added a .NET reference to the 'Microsoft.Office.Core' library?  If you downloaded the example application, the answer would be yes.  If that is the case, follow the advice in the article:

> If your system does not have Microsoft Office Outlook 2003 you may have to change the References used by the "OutlookConnector" project. That is to say, if you received a build error described as "The type of namespace name 'Outlook' could not be found", you probably don't have Office 2003. Simply expand the project references, remove the afflicted items, and add the COM Library appropriate for your system. If someone has a dynamic way to handle this, I'd be curious to see you've done.

That should solve your problem.  If not, let us know.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Visual Studio 2012, for this to work and in order to make reference to Microsoft Office Core, you have to make the reference through Visual Studio by clicking on the top menu's Project, Add Reference, Extensions button and checking office which is now (14.0).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to find PIA for Office 2013 then follow these steps:

> 1. Click on Solution Explorer in Visual Studio
> 2. Right click on your project name (not solution name)
> 3. Select 'Manage Nuget packages'
> 4. Click on Browse and search for PIA 2013, choose the shown PIA and click on Install.....

And you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble. I went to Add references, COM tab, an select Microsoft Office 15.0 Objetct Library. Ok, and my problem ends.

part of my code is:

```
EXCEL.Range rango;
            rango = (EXCEL.Range)HojadetrabajoExcel.get_Range("AE13", "AK23");
            rango.Select();
      //      EXCEL.Pictures Lafoto = (EXCEL.Pictures).HojadetrabajoExcel.Pictures(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
            EXCEL.Pictures Lafoto = HojadetrabajoExcel.Pictures(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

            HojadetrabajoExcel.Shapes.AddPicture(@"D:\GENETICA HUMANA\Reportes\imagenes\" + Variables.nombreimagen,
                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoCTrue,
                float.Parse(rango.Left.ToString()),float.Parse(rango.Top.ToString()), float.Parse(rango.Width.ToString()),
                float.Parse(rango.Height.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced  the same problem when i tried to open my old c# project into visual studio 2017 version. This problem arises typically when you try to open a project that you made with previous version of VS and open it with latest version.
**what i did is,i opened my project and delete the reference from my  project,then added Microsoft outlook 12.0 object library and  Microsoft office 12.0 object library**[Microsoft outlook 12.0 object library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUUQB.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case when I added "Microsoft Excel Object Library" and "Microsoft Office Object Library" from Reference->COM then the reference error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue, but the COM component is working fine on another computer. Suddenly, it couldn't be found on the other computer. I referred to the path of the COM component on the working computer, as shown in the picture:
[image]

path:C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\vfs\ProgramFilesCommonX86\Microsoft Shared\Office16\MSO.DLL

After adding it, everything worked as expected.