# How to write some data to excel file(.xlsx)

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

This is what I am trying to do:

1. Create an Excel file (.xlsx) c://test/files/work1_4.13.14.xlsx with name + value (date).

   example: work1_4.13.14.xlsx
2. Set headers to the file.

   example: [Name] [Age] [City].
3. I have 3 `List<string>` objects containing names, ages, and cities that I need to fill into the Excel sheet.

This is the format I would like the data to be in:

```
Name   Age  City
Ben    20   xyz
Jack   25   xyz
Mike   45   zyx
```

How can I send the data to the Excel sheet in this format?

Comment: Display the same data in Gridview and than use Export to excel form Gridview for the same.

Comment: Accepted answer is quite outdated and IMO will not be good for devs atm - if you plan on using office.interop.excel then you must have office installed in the deployed PC which is a needless dependency + if you forget to dispose then you'll bleed memory. There are other libraries out there where you DON"T need Office installed, and are much simpler to use: NPOI, ClosedXml and EPPlus being some popular alternatives. I will leave the reader to decide which is the best according to their particular needs,but I would wholeheartedly recommend the worst of those three over the office.interop dll.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Try this code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range oRng;
object misvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
try
{
    //Start Excel and get Application object.
    oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    oXL.Visible = true;

    //Get a new workbook.
    oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
    oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;

    //Add table headers going cell by cell.
    oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "First Name";
    oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Last Name";
    oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Full Name";
    oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Salary";

    //Format A1:D1 as bold, vertical alignment = center.
    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").Font.Bold = true;
    oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1").VerticalAlignment =
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

    // Create an array to multiple values at once.
    string[,] saNames = new string[5, 2];

    saNames[0, 0] = "John";
    saNames[0, 1] = "Smith";
    saNames[1, 0] = "Tom";

    saNames[4, 1] = "Johnson";

    //Fill A2:B6 with an array of values (First and Last Names).
    oSheet.get_Range("A2", "B6").Value2 = saNames;

    //Fill C2:C6 with a relative formula (=A2 & " " & B2).
    oRng = oSheet.get_Range("C2", "C6");
    oRng.Formula = "=A2 & \" \" & B2";

    //Fill D2:D6 with a formula(=RAND()*100000) and apply format.
    oRng = oSheet.get_Range("D2", "D6");
    oRng.Formula = "=RAND()*100000";
    oRng.NumberFormat = "$0.00";

    //AutoFit columns A:D.
    oRng = oSheet.get_Range("A1", "D1");
    oRng.EntireColumn.AutoFit();

    oXL.Visible = false;
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    oWB.SaveAs("c:\\test\\test505.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
        false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

    oWB.Close();
    oXL.Quit();

    //...
```

Comment: It works perfectly, but is there a possibility to do it without opening Excel? Writing directly to a file? Because it's horribly slow (writing 100k values).. And I have a feeling that the bottleneck is excel itself

Comment: @user3458958 Excellent example how ever for the headers I I would have shown this using a foreach loop if reading from a Datatable for example or a for loop

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this answer, helped me a lot.

Comment: @Lonefish 2 years late but it is possible.  Check the answer I just posted

Comment: @Lonefish you can hide the Excel by setting visible = true to visible = false .

Comment: I had to add a reference for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.  Good explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47881824/5733842

Comment: @Lonefish check my comment, using [SwiftExcel](https://github.com/RomanPavelko/SwiftExcel) you can do it extremely fast as it writes data directly to the file. There is a performance test there creating 100k rows (100 columns each) and comparing to other nuget excel output libraries.

Comment: I want to add that for me, oSheet did not have a `get_Range` method. I had to use the `_Workbook.Range` enumerable, which allowed me to use `_Workbook.Cells` objects to set my ranges. e.g. `oSheet.Range[oSheet.Cells[1, 1], oSheet.Cells[1, 2]];`

Comment: @user3458958, @MethodMan I would also suggest assigning an alias to the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace, both for readability and for ease of accessing other classes and methods beyond the initial assignment of files, workbooks, and sheets. My recommendation:
`using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Answer (score 37):

You can use [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml) for this.

Store your table in a DataTable and you can export the table to excel by this simple snippet:

```
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
DataTable table = GetYourTable();
workbook.Worksheets.Add(table );
```

You can read the documentation of ClosedXML to learn more. Hope this helps!

Comment: Great for new data, but downside here is ClosedXML's lack of intelligence to update or replace data in an existing worksheet. A common use case is to start with a template and apply data to it; ClosedXML will likely break the template if it has anything meaningful like a chart.

Answer (score 15):

It is possible to write to an excel file without opening it using the `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` and `OleDb`.  Using `OleDb`, it behaves as if you were writing to a table using sql.

Here is the code I used to create and write to an new excel file.  No extra references are needed

```
var connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\SomePath\ExcelWorkBook.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
using (var excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    // The excel file does not need to exist, opening the connection will create the
    // excel file for you
    if (excelConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open) { excelConnection.Open(); }

    // data is an object so it works with DBNull.Value
    object propertyOneValue = "cool!";
    object propertyTwoValue = "testing";

    var sqlText = "CREATE TABLE YourTableNameHere ([PropertyOne] VARCHAR(100), [PropertyTwo] INT)";

    // Executing this command will create the worksheet inside of the workbook
    // the table name will be the new worksheet name
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(sqlText, excelConnection)) { command.ExecuteNonQuery(); }

    // Add (insert) data to the worksheet
    var commandText = $"Insert Into YourTableNameHere ([PropertyOne], [PropertyTwo]) Values (@PropertyOne, @PropertyTwo)";

    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(commandText, excelConnection))
    {
        // We need to allow for nulls just like we would with
        // sql, if your data is null a DBNull.Value should be used
        // instead of null 
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyOne", propertyOneValue ?? DBNull.Value);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PropertyTwo", propertyTwoValue ?? DBNull.Value);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is the 255 character limit you will hit using ODEDB.

Answer (score 14):

Hope here is the exact what we are looking for.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateExcel("Sheet3", 4, 7, "Namachi@gmail");
}

private void UpdateExcel(string sheetName, int row, int col, string data)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oXL = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook oWB = null;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet oSheet = null;

    try
    {
        oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open("d:\\MyExcel.xlsx");
        oSheet = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sheetName) ? (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet : (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.Worksheets[sheetName];

        oSheet.Cells[row, col] = data;

        oWB.Save();

        MessageBox.Show("Done!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        if (oWB != null)
        oWB.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Recently, I tried [npoi](https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi) which **doesn't need Excel.**

As requested, let's make code that output data to `work1_4.13.14.xlsx` file like:

```
Name   Age  City
Ben    20   xyz
Jack   25   xyz
Mike   45   zyx
```

Here's code

```cs
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;
using NPOI.XSSF.UserModel;
using System.IO;

namespace ExcelWriter
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            ISheet sheet1 = workbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");

            IRow row1 = sheet1.CreateRow(0);
            row1.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Name");
            row1.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Age");
            row1.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("City");

            IRow row2 = sheet1.CreateRow(1);
            row2.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Ben");
            row2.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("20");
            row2.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("xyz");

            IRow row3 = sheet1.CreateRow(2);
            row3.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Jack");
            row3.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("25");
            row3.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("xyz");

            IRow row4 = sheet1.CreateRow(3);
            row4.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Mike");
            row4.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("45");
            row4.CreateCell(2).SetCellValue("zyx");

            FileStream sw = File.Create("work1_4.13.14.xlsx");
            workbook.Write(sw);
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't used loop just to make it easy for beginner to understand.

`.CreateRow(int index)` creates new row at specified index.
`row.CreateCell(int index)` creates new cell at specified index in row.
`cell.SetCellValue(string value)` set value at row index.

**Learn more:**

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI
Code: https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi
Examples: https://github.com/nissl-lab/npoi-examples

Answer (score 0):

Using .Net 7 and NuGet Package EPPlus we can use the following code to create the excel file requested by the OP.

Create Console application and write in the `Program.cs` file the following:

```cs
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

List<string>[] users =
{
    new()
    {
        "Ben",
        "20",
        "xyz"
    },
    new()
    {
        "Jack",
        "25",
        "xyz"
    },
    new()
    {
        "Mike",
        "45",
        "zyx"
    }
};

//change to your desired directory
string dir = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\";
string name = "work";
string extension = ".xlsx";
string fileName = $"{name}_{DateTime.Today:d.M.yy}{extension}";
string path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);

//Create a new file (if none exists at this path)
FileInfo excel = new(path);

//Using this next statement makes sure you end the process when its not needed
using ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(excel);

//Create a new worksheet
ExcelWorksheet worksheetWork = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Work");

//Create the headers by cell name
worksheetWork.Cells["A1"].Value = "Name";
worksheetWork.Cells["B1"].Value = "Age";
worksheetWork.Cells["C1"].Value = "City";

for (int row = 0; row < users.Length; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; column++)
    {
        //Add the required values to cells by row and column
        //rows and columns start from 1, in this example we need to add 1 to both,
        //and an extra 1 to row to account for the header.
        if (column is 1) //Age column
        {
             worksheetWork.Cells[row + 2, column + 1].Value = int.Parse(users[row][column]);
        }
        else
        {
             worksheetWork.Cells[row + 2, column + 1].Value = users[row][column];
        }
    }
}

package.Save();
```

Once the program runs the file is created as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Output]

Answer (score -7):

just follow below steps:

//Start Excel and get Application object.

```
oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

oXL.Visible = false;
```