# Export Umbraco fields to Excel

Tags: excel, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-contour, vba

I have 3 Umbraco Items I would like to export to an excel sheet.

```
    Alias         Type
jibberishNumber textstring
jibberishName   textstring
jiberishBody    Richtext editor
```

I would like to place them in an excel sheet like this :

```
     Number      |       Name      |    Content 
jibberishNumber  |  jibberishName  |  jiberishBody
jibberishNumber  |  jibberishName  |  jiberishBody
```

My site is structured like this

```
Root
-Content Folder
--Chapter 1 
---Section 1.1
----Story 1.1.1
----Story 1.1.2
--Chapter 2
---Section 2.1
----Story 2.1.1
----Story 2.1.2
--Chapter 3
---Section 3.1
-Content Folder
--Chapter 4
---Section 4.1
----Story 4.1.1
----Story 4.1.2
```

I want to only display stories which are a certain a document type in my site. For this particular website, it would display the results:

```
1.1.1
1.1.2
2.1.1
2.1.2
4.1.1
4.1.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [uQuery](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/) `GetNodesByType(string or int)` method, example:

```
IEnumerable<Node> nodes = uQuery.GetNodesByType("Story");
foreach (var node in nodes)
{
    var cell1 = node.GetProperty("jibberishNumber").ToString();
    var cell2 = node.GetProperty("jibberishName").ToString();
    var cell3 = node.GetProperty("jiberishBody").ToString();
}
```

As for the writing to the Excel sheet, there should be numerous topics on StackOverflow to assist with this. Example: [How to write some data to Excel file(.xlsx)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102523/1558859)