# export certain columns to certain columns in excel c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need three columns from the datagridview to export to columns a, c, and i in excel. All the data in the dataGridView needs to be visible there, but only the first three rows need to be exported.

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++ ;
}

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
        {
            objexcelapp.Cells[i + 11, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the first 3 rows, then count to 3 instead of all rows. I don't understand how you ended up with all rows

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    objexcelapp.Cells[1, i] = dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
        {
            objexcelapp.Cells[i + 11, j + 1] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

**Update**

To write to excel check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041021/how-to-write-some-data-to-excel-file-xlsx)

Comment: I stated columns. Thanks, but you didn't answer the question. the troubling part is exporting those columns to certain columns in an excel file.