# How to print a text before writing grid data to Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to print a text " This is my customer information" into an Excel file before writing `GridView` data to Excel. This text should be in top and remaining data should display below this text.

Can anyone help me? How can I do it? Please check my current code. This code just writes my `GridView` data to an Excel file.

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                //To Export all pages
                GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

                Search(null, null);

               // GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                   // row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {


                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";

                    }


                    //table.Rows.Add(title);

                }
                GridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Add the text to the gridview then put the grid in excel? You have a header row, where do you want the text to appear within the sheet?

Comment: This text should be in top row of excel. I dont want to show in gridview this text,

Comment: My advice to you is to use either Microsoft Access Redistributables (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041021/how-to-write-some-data-to-excel-file-xlsx) or DocumentFormat.OpenXML (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/) or some type of OpenXML wrapper to write your documents.  Creating them by writing directly into a file yourself is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boils down to

```
Response.Write("Some cool text added before the grid");
```

before

```
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
```

.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace AddTextToDataGridExportExcel_46000670
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static ObservableCollection<gridEntry> gridDataSource = new ObservableCollection<gridEntry>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fillDataSource();
            initializeGridView();
        }

        private void fillDataSource()
        {
            gridDataSource.Add(new gridEntry(1));
            gridDataSource.Add(new gridEntry(2));
            gridDataSource.Add(new gridEntry(3));
            gridDataSource.Add(new gridEntry(4));
            gridDataSource.Add(new gridEntry(5));
        }
        private void initializeGridView()
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = gridDataSource;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }


        protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

                //To Export all pages
                GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
                addRowToGrid();//add text within the grid
                initializeGridView();

                GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
                foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
                {
                    cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
                }
                foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
                {
                    row.BackColor = Color.White;
                    foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                        }
                        cell.CssClass = "textmode";
                    }
                }

                GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

                //style to format numbers to string
                string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
                Response.Write(style);
                Response.Write("blah blah blah");//add text before the grid
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
        }


        private void addRowToGrid()
        {
            gridDataSource.Insert(0, new gridEntry { col1 = "this is my added text" });
        }

        private GridView addRowToGridAgain(GridView gv)
        {
            return gv;
        }

        protected void btn_ClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ExportToExcel(null, null);
        }
    }

    public class gridEntry
    {
        public string col1 { get; set; }
        public string col2 { get; set; }
        public string col3 { get; set; }
        public string col4 { get; set; }
        public string col5 { get; set; }
        public string col6 { get; set; }
        public string col7 { get; set; }
        public string col8 { get; set; }

        public gridEntry()
        {
            col1 = string.Empty;
            col2 = string.Empty;
            col3 = string.Empty;
            col4 = string.Empty;
            col5 = string.Empty;
            col6 = string.Empty;
            col7 = string.Empty;
            col8 = string.Empty;
        }

        public gridEntry(int index)
        {
            col1 = "col1 " + index.ToString();
            col2 = "col2 " + index.ToString();
            col3 = "col3 " + index.ToString();
            col4 = "col4 " + index.ToString();
            col5 = "col5 " + index.ToString();
            col6 = "col6 " + index.ToString();
            col7 = "col7 " + index.ToString();
            col8 = "col8 " + index.ToString();
        }
    }

}
```

Below is YOUR snippet, *fixed*

1. `//GridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;` was throwing an error, so I commented it out. That's up to you to figure out, or ask a new question for it
2. Don't know what `Search(null, null);` does, so I commented it out

   ```
   protected void ExportToExcelPosterWay(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Response.Clear();
       Response.Buffer = true;
       Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
       Response.Charset = "";
       Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
       using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
       {
           HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

           //To Export all pages
           GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

           //Search(null, null);
           initializeGridView();

           // GridView1.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
           foreach (TableCell cell in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
           {
               cell.BackColor = GridView1.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
           }
           foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
           {
               // row.BackColor = Color.White;
               foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
               {


                   if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
                   {
                       cell.BackColor = GridView1.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       cell.BackColor = GridView1.RowStyle.BackColor;
                   }
                   cell.CssClass = "textmode";

               }


               //table.Rows.Add(title);

           }
           //GridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
           GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

           //style to format numbers to string
           string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
           Response.Write(style);
           Response.Write("Some cool text added before the grid");
           Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
           Response.Flush();
           Response.End();
       }
   }
   ```