# Send Text to Another Application C# WPF Runnable on Windows

Tags: c#, wpf, findwindow

I have simple TCP/IP Server Windows and Client Android. How I can send received text to another appilication for example notepad or excel cell, any window application with input field. Data Received in background

```
 private void Events_DataRecieved(object sender, SimpleTcp.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ipandPort = e.IpPort;
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data);
        Console.WriteLine(data);  
        Send(data);
    }
```

I try this

```
 [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public void Send(String data)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process[] p = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); //search for process notepad
        if (p.Length > 0) //check if window was found
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(p[0].MainWindowHandle); //bring notepad to foreground
        }

        SendKeys.SendWait(data); //send key to notepad
    }
```

How I can send text to any application runnuble on PC after DataRecieved. Like https://barcodetopc.com/ here
Thx for help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you are using the SimpleTcp Nuget package. You can use several 3rd party applications to control the data exchange. Examples of these applications are [Hercules](https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility) or [Docklight](https://docklight.de/downloads/).

You can create a server in Hercules with your own IP address and the port you specify. Just come to the server tab and say Listen.

In C# application, you can first create a Client.

```
string IpAddress = "192.168.1.40"; // Example Ip Address
string Port = "23";

public SimpleTcpClient tcpClient = new SimpleTcpClient(Ip, Convert.ToInt32(Port), false, null, null);
tcpClient.Connect();

if (tcpClient.IsConnected)
{
    tcpClient.Events.DataReceived += Events_DataReceived;
    tcpClient.Events.Connected += Events_Connected;
    tcpClient.Events.Disconnected += Events_Disconnected;
}
```

If you want to listen to messages sent to you

```
private void Events_DataRecieved(object sender, SimpleTcp.DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        string IpPort = e.IpPort;
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Data);
        Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

If you want to send a message

```
byte[] message = new byte[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
private void EthernetSend()
{
    
    tcpClient.Send("Message"); // If you want to send a string expression
    tcpClient.Send(message); // If you want to send a hexadecimal expression
}
```

Comment: I already have client and server, I can recieve message from clent by anroid and Server. Question is how send recived data to Another Application like Execel for example https://barcodetopc.com/

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Writing or reading data to Excel is a very different task. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041021/how-to-write-some-data-to-excel-file-xlsx) link solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by using Clipboard

```
    public void Send2(String data)
    {

        Thread thread = new Thread(() => System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(data));
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();

        SendKeys.SendWait("^v");

    }
```